# API for releasing actions to Github Marketplace

Tags: github, automation, github-api, release-management, github-actions

Is there an API or a programmatic way to release an action to Github Marketplace? Most actions/APIs are for creating a release in the Repo itself but releasing to marketplace seems like a UI only feature. Does anyone if there's an API or cli method for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

It is true, as mentioned in  [GitHub Marketplace](https://developer.github.com/marketplace/), that:

> Anyone can publish an action in GitHub Marketplace as long as they meet the terms of service. Unlike apps, GitHub Actions listed in GitHub Marketplace are not verified by GitHub.

In that regard, the process could benefit from an API.

But while there is a [GitHub Marketplace API](https://developer.github.com/marketplace/integrating-with-the-github-marketplace-api/github-marketplace-rest-api-endpoints/), it does not include the publication process itself, which [remains a manual process for now.](https://help.github.com/en/actions/building-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace#publishing-an-action)